# Trying to find two items in an array that add up to a target value python

Tags: python

This code:

```
array = [0, 5, 3, 6, 7, 2]
relay = 13
index = 0
lengthArray = len(array)

#indentify primary elements
for count in range(index, lengthArray):
  #identify a possible target
  pTarget = relay - array[count]
  #identify secondary elements
  for count2 in range(index, lengthArray):
    if pTarget == array[index]:
      print(pTarget)
    if pTarget != array[index] and index != lengthArray:
      index += 1
    if pTarget != array[index] and index == lengthArray:
      index = 0
```

results in this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    if pTarget != array[index] and index == lengthArray:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I'm expecting an output from pTarget
Can you help?

Comment: It looks to me like you are using `array[index]` where you mean to be using `array[count2]`?

Comment: I also think the issue could be that the three if statements should be if elif elif instead

Comment: Length of an array is how many elements it has. If it has 6 elements, it will be 6. If you want to loop through it, you need to go from 0 to 5 not from 0 to 6, so do: `lengthArray = len(array) - 1` . Then you will get `pTarget` without a problem but just eyeballing this array it will give you `7`, you still need the other number (`6`) that added together with `7` gives `13`.

Comment: For everyone else, OP asked for help not for a new code. When a new contributor posts a beginner question, do your best to explain to them how to solve their problem and where they went wrong instead of copying the first code snippet you get from ChatGPT for the reputation.

Answer (score 2):

For each value in the list search for an element that is equal to the target minus that value:

```
def find(lst: list[int], target: int) -> list[tuple[int, int]]:
    rv: list[tuple[int, int]] = []
    for i, v in enumerate(lst, 1):
        if (k := target - v) in lst[i:]:
            rv.append((v, k))
    return rv

print(find([0, 5, 3, 6, 7, 2], 8))
```

**Output:**

```
[(5, 3), (6, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED TO USE ONLY ONCE EACH ELEMENT OF ARRAY**

I think its mostly few errors and typos:

> I removed the unnecessary index and count2 variables, as they were causing confusion.
> In the secondary loop, I changed the variable name from count2 to count for clarity.
> I directly used array[count] in the inner loop to compare with pTarget to find the secondary element.
> I've added the print of the index of each element in the array and added an exit() so it prints only once the pair found (can be removed if needed).

Tell me what you think of the solution:

```py
array = [0, 5, 3, 6, 7, 2]
relay = 13
lengthArray = len(array)

pair_found = False

# Identify primary elements
for index in range(lengthArray):
    primary_element = array[index]
    pTarget = relay - primary_element
    
    # Keep track of used primary elements
    used_primary_elements = set()
    
    # Identify secondary elements
    for count in range(index + 1, lengthArray):
        if pTarget == array[count] and primary_element not in used_primary_elements:
            print("Pair found:", primary_element, pTarget)
            print("Indexes of pair elements:", index, count)
            used_primary_elements.add(primary_element)
            pair_found = True

if not pair_found:
    print("No pair found")
```

Comment: This doesn't work for all target (relay) values. If *relay == 14* then the output is 7 7 but there is only one 7 in the list

Comment: This outputs:
Pair found: 6 7
Index of primary element: 3
Index of secondary element: 4

Comment: Sure it works for a value of 13 but it's not a general solution. And quite why you're calling *exit()* is very mysterious

Comment: Here's a fix ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

- Make the second for loop start at count+1, so that you don't use the same element twice in a pair.
- Compare pTarget with array[count2] because that's actually what you want to compare.
- Delete last conditions because indexing is what's causing the error and incrementation is no longer necessary.

Here's what it would look like:

```py
array = [0, 5, 3, 6, 7, 2]
relay = 13
lengthArray = len(array)

#indentify primary elements
for count in range(lengthArray):
  #identify a possible target
  pTarget = relay - array[count]
  #identify secondary elements
  for count2 in range(count+1, lengthArray):
    if pTarget == array[count2]:
      print(pTarget)
```

I hope this helped.